# Dynamic static table view

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview

Ok, so there is "static cells" content mode for creating settings-like views. Can anyone suggest how to deal with that if you have different number of settings to be displayed in different circumstances?
i.e. in one case I have three cells: two cells with switches and one with button, and in other case - just last cell with button.

Should I switch back to dynamic cells? How should I handle headers' behavior in this case?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you better use dynamic cells. 
for header and footer of cells and sections you can just call this methods:

```
- (NSString *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section  
{  
    return @"This will be the header!!!!";  
}
```

or

```
- (NSString *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section  
{  
    return @"This will be the footer!!!!";  
}
```

P.S. there were some methods, something like `"viewForHeaderInSection"` and `"viewForFooterInSecton"`. But I don't remembre the complete implementation.

P.S^2. you have to set the Table View Style to Grouped!
[See this image for a tiny help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnOYv.png)

[image]

Comment: unfortunately, i need header views to go away with cells while scrolling.

Comment: what do you mean by go away? you mean something like static cell headers that scrolls with the whole table?

Comment: exactly. common behavior for uitableview's headers - is to stay on top of the tableview while scrolling. to avoid this, one can use static cells.

Comment: these methods works exactly as you want, they add an string as a header of a dynamic cell section, that scrolls. BUT do NOT forget to set the Table View Style as `Grouped`. As if it is set to `plain` the header will stock to the top of your view.

Comment: i need custom header views, but it seems to work this way. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Static cells and a simple `if` in your implementation of `numberOfRowsInSection:` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to return your 3 static cells or just the last one depending on your condition. Simple enough.

Comment: `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` returns nil in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Why would you like to call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` if you chose to use static cells ans not dynamic ones?!?

Comment: i would like to design cells in interface builder inside tableview in storyboard, not creating special xib for each cell separately